# ComboBox Items are not Saving into DataBase in C#

Tags: c#, winforms, combobox

I am having a problem regarding `ComboBox`. I have a ComboBox that has 2 Items. Now i want to select one of them and save it into database. But I have got an error regarding Conversion Failed when Converting the NVARCHAR Value.

> Conversion failed when converting the nvarchar value
>   'System.Data.DataRowView' to data type int

I have a field for that ComboBox in Database Table which has a VARCHAR(50) Data Type. And Please Explain it that why i got an error? Here is the Code

```
private void InsertCourseDetail()
{
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(tbID.Text) == true)
    {
        CS = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["UMSdbConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(CS))
        {
            con.Open();
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT ISNULL(MAX(course_id),0)+1 FROM CourseDetail", con);
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            tbID.Text = cmd.ExecuteScalar().ToString();
            {
                using (SqlCommand cmd1 = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO [dbo].[CourseDetail] (course_id,hec_code,course_type,FK_pro_id,course_cre_hour)VALUES(@course_id,@hec_code,@course_type,@FK_pro_id,@course_cre_hour )", con))
                {
                    cmd1.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                    cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@course_id", tbID.Text);
                    cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@hec_code", tbHECCode.Text);
                    cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@course_type", (cBoxCourseType.SelectedItem == null) ? "NULL" : cBoxCourseType.SelectedItem.ToString());
                    cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FK_pro_id", (cBoxProgram.SelectedItem == null) ? "NULL" : cBoxProgram.SelectedItem.ToString());
                    cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@course_cre_hour", (cBoxCreditHours.SelectedItem == null) ? "NULL" : cBoxCreditHours.SelectedItem.ToString());
                    cmd1.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    con.Close();
                    MessageBox.Show("Record Has been Saved Successfully !", "Info", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
                    FillGridView();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What error message your getting. put it in try catch and see.

Comment: @PavanChandaka Conversion failed when converting the nvarchar value 'System.Data.DataRowView' to data type int.

Comment: I think the problem is here cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FK_pro_id", (cBoxProgram.SelectedItem == null) ? "NULL" : cBoxProgram.SelectedItem.ToString()); is your "FK_pro_id" in database is int or integer type?

Comment: @PavanChandaka With this code cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FK_pro_id", (cBoxProgram.SelectedIndex == -1) ? 0 : cBoxProgram.SelectedValue);
First time the record is saved but then again got an error

Comment: Could you please tell me whats the error?

Comment: @Pavan ComboBox values i wanna save to database is not saving..getting an error Conversion failed

Comment: you have some conversion error. Use "Convert"  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.convert(v=vs.110).aspx , to convert to the same types as database type before passing it to "cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue"

Comment: Try to use `.Text`?

Comment: @Law Not working with the Text

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are receiving a run-time error:

> Conversion failed when converting the nvarchar value
>   'System.Data.DataRowView' to data type int.

That's because you tried to set value of parameter using `SelectedItem` of your combo box controls. In fact `SelectedItem` of your combo boxes are `DataRowView`. If you have set a `ValueMember` for thoes `ComboBox` controls you can use their `SelectedValue`, otherwise you can cast `SelectedItem` to `DataRowView` and read the field which you want. For example:

```
var value = comboBox1.SelectedValue;
```

or

```
var value = ((DataRowView)comboBox1.SelectedItem)["Id"];
```

Comment: You may need some null checking though.

Comment: did work with that `cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FK_pro_id", (Convert.ToBoolean(cBoxProgram.SelectedValue = -1))? 0 : cBoxProgram.SelectedValue);`

Comment: So it seems the post answers your question :)

Comment: I already put a condition  `cBoxProgram.SelectedValue = -1))? 0 :`  if it is -1 means Nothing Selected Then Save '0' ..Otherwise save the Selected Value .. right?

Comment: I know you can extract the value using `comboBox1.SelectedValue` but honestly I don't have any idea about what the value means to you.

Comment: Sir can we chat on this?

Comment: Ask your question here, no problem :)

Comment: i want to show you what i want with picture but here i can't send the pictures that's why

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/126817/discussion-between-reza-aghaei-and-kh-aafi).

Comment: When you set a `DataTable` as data source of a ComboBox , the items would be of type `DataRowView`.  So always you can get value of `SomeColumn` from `SeletedItem` this way: `var value = ((DataRowView)comboBox1.SelectedItem)["SomeColumn"];`. Also if you have set `ValueMember`, then `SelectedValue` of `ComboBox` will contain the value of the field which you set as selected value. Also if you set `DisplayMember`, then `Text` of `ComboBox` contains the value of the field which you set as display member.

Comment: I believe these information is enough to answer your question and you can simply get any value from combo boxes using this answer. To be honest, I really have no idea about how can more help be possible in this situation :)

Answer (score 1):

Solved..!!!

```
cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FK_pro_id", (Convert.ToBoolean(cBoxProgram.SelectedValue = -1))? 0 : cBoxProgram.SelectedValue);
```